# What happens if you try to release an object that has been released?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

What if I have an object, say NSIndexPath in which before I do a copy I always release it first?

Is it possible to have a memory count under 0? 
I am doing this to prevent memory leaks.. is this a good way?

//global already has some value before in here or it doesn't have a value.. I want to update
 //this with a new value (I no longer care to the old pointer)

```
 [global release]
 global = [indexPath copy];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't. When the retain count reaches 0, your object will be dealloc'ed and its pointer will become invalid, so using it again will cause unpredictable results (namely crashing).

You should read through Apple's [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i).

*This is the fundamental rule:*

- *You only release or autorelease objects you own. You take ownership of an object if you create it using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you send it a retain message.*
- *You use release or autorelease to relinquish ownership of an object. autorelease just means “send a release message in the future” (specifically: when the used autorelease pool receives a drain message).*

**Update:**

As Josh pointed out, the one case you need to consider is when global and indexPath are the same. In that case, you would still "need" the pointer (to perform the copy), so you either autorelease (instead of releasing) or you use a temporary variable to handle that.

Comment: As an addendum to this post, looking at the retainCount is almost always the wrong thing to do. So don't do it, not even for "debugging" purposes.

Comment: I have read this.. I am just now trying to prevent memory leak as I have a copy and I am finding a hard spot of when to release it. It does have to be released before I do another copy using that variable

Comment: It's all about ownership. When you need to "take ownership" of the object, you increase its retain count (whether it is through an explicit `retain` message, or by using alloc, new, copy, or mutableCopy). When you no longer need it, you `release` it. Just figure out when you're done with it and that's when you can release it.

Comment: @Andre I think you definitely get my point, the reason why I am releasing before I do a copy is because I do not care anymore of the object as I am ready to get a new one.. and I want to prevent memory leak by doing so... so is this a valid point then? I updated my question above just to make it clear

Comment: Can you explain the situation you have where you must release a variable before copying it? Is there a reason `autorelease` won't work for your purposes?

Comment: Also, listen to what jer said. There's no need to look at retain counts. As long as you're following the guidelines everywhere, you're fine. You can also use Build & Analyze to help track down the source of your leaks; or use Instruments.

Comment: I am still unclear of the concept of autorelease, it seems that it will be released in the future, but not definite of exactly when.. it says when the used autorelease pool receives a drain message, but when is this? And this is why I don't want to use autorelease.. I know that before I do a copy to something, I want to disregard the previous object and therefore I am releasing... is this wrong?

Comment: @adit But if you're going to copy it, you do need it. You can only say you no longer need it after copying it...

Comment: @Andre yes when I copy it that means I need it.. that's why I am releasing before a copy... if I release after the copy then it's a different story right?

Comment: before I do a copy, global will reference to some object that has previously been copied before.. I don't need this anymore and therefore I am releasing it before I get a new reference to a new object using copy

Comment: Sorry, I only saw your code now. I thought you were releasing the object you were copying, but that's now what's happening. So yeah, if you retained `global` before, then yeah, it makes sense to release it before assigning a new pointer to the global variable.

Comment: Regarding autorelease, you'd better read the docs (or if you're still unclear, you can ask a new question). But most of the time, you can really just think of autorelease as being "release at the end of the current event cycle".

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is essentially correct, so long as `global` either has an old value that you no longer need or is `nil`. If it is one of a class's ivars, it will be `nil` when an instance of the class is created. The one catch is that if the new `indexPath` happens to be the same object as the one that's already in `global`, you will have over-released and you will crash.

```
// global points to object at 0x8BADFOOD
// indexPath also happens to be 0x8BADFOOD; for some reason, it
// hasn't changed since last time. This _can_ happen.
[global release];    // object at 0x8BADFOOD is deallocated
global = [indexPath copy];    // indexPath no longer valid! 
                              // Crash! Bang! Boom!
```

The way to avoid this is to use a temp variable.

When you declare a property as `copy` and synthesize that property, the setter method that is created looks essentially like this, and you can do the same thing:

```
- (void)setMyFloozit:(Floozit *)newFloozit {
    // Copy first in case newFloozit and myFloozit are for
    // some reason the same object
    // Take ownership of a copy of newFloozit
    Floozit * tmp = [newFloozit copy];
    // We no longer need old value of myFloozit, so we release it.
    [myFloozit release]; 
    // tmp contains a value that we own, we just need to assign
    // it to the correct name.
    myFloozit = tmp;
}
```

<sub>This could be made slightly better by checking first to see whether `newFloozit` and `myFloozit` are the same, and doing nothing if they are.</sub>